# How to display user submitted nodes in the node detail view of the same user?

Tags: entities

I'm aware of such modules as Relation and Entity reference but I can't figure out how I make automatic relation between nodes that depend on the user that submitted those nodes.

Site has users A, B, C ... Let's say user A submits 10 nodes. When any user clicks on any of his nodes you can see his other 9 submitted nodes in the detailed view. When you click on node submitted by user B you can see his other submitted nodes and so on. This should work automatically without manually building relations between nodes.

How do I achieve this?

Thanks a lot
Ray

Comment: I think you should be able to achive this using a view that will query all nodes but the current one that has the same author. You would then have to load and execute this view in your `node.tpl` or perhaps `node-<type>.tpl` file.

Comment: I would post an answer, but Krister Andersson already nailed it, although the exact rendering mode of the view is not in scope of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the following and it seems to work:

1. Create a new block view
2. Add a Contextual filter of type `Content: Nid`
3. Add a relationship of type `Content: Author` (Required)
4. Add a relationship of type `User: Content authored` that uses the previous relationship and is required
5. Under Format you set `Show: Content | Full Content` - You must also use the `User: Content authored` relationship for this one

You could also change the number of related nodes that will be shown and also you might wan't to add a filter of `Content: Type` to restrict what kind of nodes to display. Notice that you could create a template for a specific content-type ie `node--<YOUR_CONTENT_TYPE>.tpl` and load and execute the view from there.

In you `node.tpl` file you would load this view doing something similar to:

```
$view = views_get_view('YOUR_VIEW_NAME');
$view->set_display('YOUR_VIEW_BLOCK_NAME');
$view->set_arguments(array($node->nid));
$view->execute();
echo $view->render();
```

*Note* I think you should specify every field you wan't to use, in other words you shouldn't use `Show: Content | Full Content` - because this will result in an infinite loop. I don't think this is a complete solution, but perhaps it will point you in the right direction.

If you are using fields in the view you could create a separate template named `views-view-fields--YOUR_VIEW_NAME--YOUR_VIEW_BLOCK_NAME.tpl` that will be used to output the actual fields.

To exclude the current node from the listing you need to modify your contextual filter.

- Click the `More` button for `Content: Nid` and choose `exclude` you should also make this filter use your relationship for `Content: Authored`

Comment: Thanks a lot Krister. It worked. Except that I get this erro now in admin console and somethimes it apears on front end: http://screencast.com/t/Ing9HBjCKMU any idea how to fix this? Also in Node detail page I can see node duplicates now - the node that is opened and the same node together with user related nodes in the attached view. I believe i can exclude it by taking node ID from url but in contextual filters it seems that theres no NOT TO display option as in regular filters theres no "get content ID from url" option

Comment: @Ray - What Drupal and views version are you running? Perhaps this http://drupal.org/node/1556174 is related to your problem with the `dom_id`. I will check to see if I can find I way to exclude the current node from the view (I think I've succeeded with this before=)

Comment: I'm running Drupal 7.17 and Views 3.5, thanks for the link will try to find answers there :)

Comment: I have found the answer, I update my answer, hold on=)

Comment: Your solution is good
but still
Add a relationship of type User: Content authored that uses the previous relationship and is required it should be Add a Filter of type User: Content authored that uses the previous relationship and is required